# Find & Delete subroutine are not working in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

User enters the Waypoint id and then press delete record it, so data of that particular waypoint id should be delete from observations table.
Written a subroutine where my vba code first find the waypoint id in the observation worksheet, get the row number and then delete the row number and move the cell up. If it doesnot find the waypoint id then message should appear Waypoint id not found and cannot be deleted.

My vba code is not working. Can anyone help me to fix this issue? Attach File with name [Problem.xlsm](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MvRASwP_Plp75ESXFYXQEpZQEShbk-GZ/view?usp=sharing)

[image]
[image]

```
Sub FindRecord(WyPt)

    Dim Value As String
    
    WyPtRow = 0
    
    ReadRow = 2
    Value = Cells(ReadRow, 2).Select  'Observation Sheet-WayPointID
    
    While Value <> ""
        
        If WyPt = Value Then
            
            WyPtRow = ReadRow
            Exit Sub
            
        End If
        
        ReadRow = ReadRow + 1
        Value = Cells(ReadRow, 2)
    Wend
    
End Sub

Sub DeleteRecord()
    
   Set DEFrm = Sheets("DataEntryForm")
   Set ObsData = Sheets("Observations")

   WyPt = Trim(DEFrm.Cells(6, 2))   'DataEntryForm worksheet-WayPointID
    
   Call FindRecord(WyPt)
    
    If WyPtRow > 0 Then
       Worksheets("Observations").Rows(WyPtRow).Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
       MsgBox "WaypointID found", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Deleted Succesfully"
    End If
    
    If WyPtRow = 0 Then
        MsgBox "WaypointID Not found", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "We can't delete the record"
        Exit Sub
        
    End If
    
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use application.match to find the row to delete.
I have not downloaded your file so this may need to adjustments.

```
Sub FindRecord()
    Set DEFrm = Sheets("DataEntryForm")

    WyPt = Trim(DEFrm.Cells(6, 2).value)
    WyPtRow  = application.match(WyPt, range("B:B"),0)
    if not iserror(WyPtRow) then
        DeleteRecord(WyPtRow)
    else
        msgbox "No waypoint found"
    end if
End sub

Sub DeleteRecord(WyPtRow)
    Worksheets("Observations").Rows(WyPtRow).EntireRow.Delete
End sub
```

Edit sorry I see now that I made the code in reverse.
My idea was to call FindRecord and it calls delete, I see now that you called Delete and it called find.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
Sub DelRow(WyPt As String)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To 65536
        If Cells(i, 2).Text = WyPt Then
            Worksheets("Observations").Rows(i).Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
            MsgBox "WaypointID found", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Deleted Succesfully"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If Cells(i, 2).Text = "" Then 'stop on first empty row
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox "WaypointID Not found", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "We can't delete the record"
End Sub
```